# What is the correct way to at Semantics for a Screen-Reader to a horizontal scrolling PageView?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to at semantics to the horizontal scrolling `PageView` that is the main feature of my apps intro-pages. But the next/previous-element-gesture (swipe left to right or reversed) the screen-reader uses, collides with the horizontal scrolling of `PageView`. So I did a little research and found this [article](https://blog.gskinner.com/archives/2022/09/flutter-crafting-a-great-experience-for-screen-readers.html), thats presents a good solution to the problem inclusive an code [example](https://github.com/gskinnerTeam/flutter-wonderous-app/blob/master/lib/ui/screens/intro/intro_screen.dart). The proposed solution is to override the up-down-gesture of the screen-reader, as long the `PageView` as focus, and replace it with skipping though the "pages" (for lack of a better therm) of the `PageView`. So the next/previous-element-gesture is untouched. You can do this by adding an `Semantic` and providing callbacks for `onIncrease` and `onDecrease`. Even better when you do so the screen-reader explains to the user that there is an scrollable element and how it can be used.

```
final List<Widget> pages = pageData.map((e) => _Page(data: e)).toList(); // Just StatelessWidgets

//...

MergeSemantics(
  child: Semantics(
    onIncrease: () => _handleSemanticSwipe(1),
    onDecrease: () => _handleSemanticSwipe(-1),
    child: PageView(
      controller: _pageController,
      children: pages,
      onPageChanged: (_) => AppHaptics.lightImpact(),
    ),
  ),
),

//...

void _handleSemanticSwipe(int dir) {
  _pageController.animateToPage((_pageController.page ?? 0).round() + dir,
      duration: $styles.times.fast, curve: Curves.easeOut);
}
```

However it struggle the recreate the presented results in my app. When I wrap the `PageView` in a `MergeSemantics` as proposed, the "pages" inclusive the scrollable element are read out loud. The problem is, that no only is the current "page" is read, but the previous and next "page" are read as well. I suppose this because `PageView` loads this pages in advance and the `MergeSemantic` collapses there semantic subtree as well.

- When I wrap the `PageView` in a normal `Semantic` the up-down-gestures do not trigger.
- When I wrap the "pages" in and provide the functions this works, as long as the `PageView` covers the entire screen. As soon the `viewportFraction` is below `1.0` multiple "pages" are read. I thinks this is because multiple pages are on the screen, so they are read.
- I tried an `IndexedSemantic` around the "pages", but this reads the current and the next "page" on skipping and than the next "page" again.

Can someone explain the correct way to do this to me? I am poking in the dark here, because unfortunately I only vaguely understand how the semantics-tree is build in flutter and can find good explanations. **To clarify: I want to skip between "pages" with to up-down-gesture when the `PageView` or "pages" have focus. I want to still be able to use the left-right-gestures to get to the next element. Because there are buttons on this "pages", I should be able the reach. I want to have the current "page" and only the current "page" and the scrollable element read out, after I skipped to a page.**

P.S.: There also seems to be a [problem](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/41134) regarding merging the `Semantics` of an `RichText`, which a few of my "pages" unfortunately are using.